# Busqueda de comparacion

Tags: prolog

buenas tardes amigos  estoy trabajando en un recomendador en prolog..
pero mi duda es... como puedo  hacer una consulta donde le pregunte al programa..
 ¿cuales son las peliculas de: star wars? (por ejemplo)

teniendo en cuenta que tengo una base de conocimiento y tengo toda la saga de star wars, y solo quiero saber los nombre o las peliculas que tengo sobre star wars.

```
    :- module('Base de conocimeintos',
  [records/1 % entradas reales de la base de datos
  ,schema/1  % Esquema de registros opcional: puede ser útil para el mantenimiento / documentación
  ,record/1  % validador simple
  ]).

% comprobar que el tipo de registro es conocido
%y tiene todos los campos definidos correctamente

record(R) :-
  records(R),
  dict_pairs(R,T,As),
  schema(S),
  dict_pairs(S,T,Bs),
  maplist([K-_,K-_]>>true,As,Bs).

schema(libro{
  titulo:string,
  categoria:string,
  autor:string,
  np:integer,
  anio:_,    % no importa el tipo (pero, por supuesto, debe definir su validador de año / 1 o de anio / 1)
  isbn:isbn, % tipo personalizado: implementar un isbn / 1 para validar (quizás un DCG[Gramatica de Cláusulas definidas])
  editorial:string
}).


schema(pelicula{
  titulo:_,
  director:_,
  escritor:_,
  produccion:_,
  protagonistas:_,
  genero:_,
  clasificacion:_,
  idioma:_,
  calidad:_,
  anio:_,
  pais:_,
  duracion:_
}).
schema(musica{
  titulo:_,
  genero:_,
  cantante:_,
  escritor:_,
  idioma:_,
  album:_,
  productora:_,
  pais:_
}).


/*
 * Base de conocimientos de
 * Peliculas
 * Pelicula(titulo,director,escritor,produccion,
 * genero,clasificacion,idioma,calidad,año,pais,duracion)
 */

    records(pelicula{
  titulo:'Star Wars Episodio IV: Una nueva esperanza',
  director:'Mike Mitchell',
  escritor:'Phil Lord_Rosemery Louis',
  produccion:'Dan Lin,Phil Lord, Denik Pol',
  protagonistas:'Chris Pratt,Elizabeth Banks,Tiffany Haddish,Will Arnett,Stephanie Beatriz',
  genero:'Accion,Aventura,Ciencia ficcion',
  clasificacion:'Adulto',
  idioma:'Ingles',
  calidad:'HD',
  anio:1977,
  pais:'EEUU',
  duracion:'160 minutos'
}).


records(pelicula{
  titulo:'Star Wars Episodio V: El Imperio contraataca',
  director:'Mike Mitchell, Paul G',
  escritor:'Phil Lord,Rosemery Louis',
  produccion:'Dan Lin,Phil Lord, Denik Pol',
  protagonistas:'Chris Pratt,Elizabeth Banks,Tiffany Haddish,Will Arnett,Stephanie Beatriz',
  genero:'Accion,Aventura,Ciencia ficcion',
  clasificacion:'Adulto',
  idioma:'Ingles',
  calidad:'HD',
  anio:1980,
  pais:'EEUU',
  duracion:'150 minutos'
}).

records(pelicula{
  titulo:'Star Wars Episodio VI: El retorno del Jedi',
  director:'Mike Mitchell, Paul G',
  escritor:'Phil Lord,Rosemery Louis',
  produccion:'Dan Lin,Phil Lord, Denik Pol',
  protagonistas:'Chris Pratt,Elizabeth Banks,Tiffany Haddish,Will Arnett,Stephanie Beatriz',
  genero:'Accion,Aventura,Ciencia ficcion',
  clasificacion:'Adulto',
  idioma:'Ingles',
  calidad:'HD',
  anio:1983,
  pais:'EEUU',
  duracion:'150 minutos'
}).

records(pelicula{
  titulo:'Star Wars Episodio I: La amenaza Fantasma',
  director:'Mike Mitchell, Paul G',
  escritor:'Phil Lord,Rosemery Louis',
  produccion:'Dan Lin,Phil Lord, Denik Pol',
  protagonistas:'Chris Pratt,Elizabeth Banks,Tiffany Haddish,Will Arnett,Stephanie Beatriz',
  genero:'Accion,Aventura,Ciencia ficcion',
  clasificacion:'Adulto',
  idioma:'Ingles',
  calidad:'HD',
  anio:1997,
  pais:'EEUU',
  duracion:'156 minutos'
}).

records(pelicula{
  titulo:'Star Wars Episodio II: El ataque de los clones',
  director:'Mike Mitchell, Paul G',
  escritor:'Phil Lord,Rosemery Louis',
  produccion:'Dan Lin,Phil Lord, Denik Pol',
  protagonistas:'Chris Pratt,Elizabeth Banks,Tiffany Haddish,Will Arnett,Stephanie Beatriz',
  genero:'Accion,Aventura,Ciencia ficcion',
  clasificacion:'Adulto',
  idioma:'Ingles',
  calidad:'HD',
  anio:2002,
  pais:'EEUU',
  duracion:'345 minutos'
}).
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando una característica muy interesante que de momento te puedo confirmar que se usa en [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog), y se le conoce como ***dicts***.

Un dict no se consulta de manera normal mediante un predicado

```
records(X),pelicula(X).
```

> ERROR: Undefined procedure: pelicula/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Podemos definir un dict simplemente mediante

```
VariableDeTipoDict = nombre_del_dict{propiedad1,propiedadN}
```

Si en alguna regla queremos sacar el valor de una propiedad usamos el punto para ello

```
inicio:-
    VariableDeTipoDict = nombre_del_dict{propiedad1:valor_propiedad_1,propiedadN:valor_propiedad_N},
    write(VariableDeTipoDict.nombre_de_propiedad)
.
```

ahora si no te sabes el nombre de la propiedad pero aún así deseas buscar algo en las propiedades, también puedes usar variables después del punto de esta manera:

```
inicio:-
    VariableDeTipoDict = nombre_del_dict{propiedad1:valor_propiedad_1,propiedadN:valor_propiedad_N},
    VariableDeTipoDict.Nombre_de_propiedad = 'valor',
    write(VariableDeTipoDict)
.
```

Por todo lo anterior, podrías hacer la consulta mediante:

```
records(Pelicula), sub_string(Pelicula.titulo,_,_,_,'Star Wars').
```

Obteniendo la siguiente salida

> Pelicula = pelicula{anio:1977, calidad:'HD', clasificacion:'Adulto', director:'Mike Mitchell', duracion:'160 minutos', escritor:'Phil Lord_Rosemery Louis', genero:'Accion,Aventura,Ciencia ficcion', idioma:'Ingles', pais:'EEUU', produccion:'Dan Lin,Phil Lord, Denik Pol', protagonistas:'Chris Pratt,Elizabeth Banks,Tiffany Haddish,Will Arnett,Stephanie Beatriz', titulo:'Star Wars Episodio IV: Una nueva esperanza'}

```
;
```

> Pelicula = pelicula{anio:1980, calidad:'HD', clasificacion:'Adulto', director:'Mike Mitchell, Paul G', duracion:'150 minutos', escritor:'Phil Lord,Rosemery Louis', genero:'Accion,Aventura,Ciencia ficcion', idioma:'Ingles', pais:'EEUU', produccion:'Dan Lin,Phil Lord, Denik Pol', protagonistas:'Chris Pratt,Elizabeth Banks,Tiffany Haddish,Will Arnett,Stephanie Beatriz', titulo:'Star Wars Episodio V: El Imperio contraataca'}

```
;
```

> Pelicula = pelicula{anio:1983, calidad:'HD', clasificacion:'Adulto', director:'Mike Mitchell, Paul G', duracion:'150 minutos', escritor:'Phil Lord,Rosemery Louis', genero:'Accion,Aventura,Ciencia ficcion', idioma:'Ingles', pais:'EEUU', produccion:'Dan Lin,Phil Lord, Denik Pol', protagonistas:'Chris Pratt,Elizabeth Banks,Tiffany Haddish,Will Arnett,Stephanie Beatriz', titulo:'Star Wars Episodio VI: El retorno del Jedi'}

```
;
```

> Pelicula = pelicula{anio:1997, calidad:'HD', clasificacion:'Adulto', director:'Mike Mitchell, Paul G', duracion:'156 minutos', escritor:'Phil Lord,Rosemery Louis', genero:'Accion,Aventura,Ciencia ficcion', idioma:'Ingles', pais:'EEUU', produccion:'Dan Lin,Phil Lord, Denik Pol', protagonistas:'Chris Pratt,Elizabeth Banks,Tiffany Haddish,Will Arnett,Stephanie Beatriz', titulo:'Star Wars Episodio I: La amenaza Fantasma'}

```
;
```

> Pelicula = pelicula{anio:2002, calidad:'HD', clasificacion:'Adulto', director:'Mike Mitchell, Paul G', duracion:'345 minutos', escritor:'Phil Lord,Rosemery Louis', genero:'Accion,Aventura,Ciencia ficcion', idioma:'Ingles', pais:'EEUU', produccion:'Dan Lin,Phil Lord, Denik Pol', protagonistas:'Chris Pratt,Elizabeth Banks,Tiffany Haddish,Will Arnett,Stephanie Beatriz', titulo:'Star Wars Episodio II: El ataque de los clones'}

```
;
```

> false.

Lo que usé para buscar subcadenas es un predicado [substring/5](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sub_string/5), pero no asumas que es la única solución posible.