# Sintaxis de formular una pregunta en prolog

Tags: prolog

Estoy trabajando en un recomendador de películas, 
y con una base de conocimientos.
y en ella tengo todas las películas de Stars Wars. 
y solo quiero  que me aparezcan solamente los títulos de las películas de Stars Wars.

¿Cómo puedo formular unas pregunta en **prolog**?

¿Cuáles son las películas de Stars Wars?

Quiero hacer la consulta conforme a esto, pero me sale error en:

```
records(R), R >:< pelicula{titulo:T["Stars Wars"]}.
```

> eror:ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
>   ERROR: records(R), R >:< pelicula{titulo:
>   ERROR: ** here **
>   ERROR: T["Stars Wars"]} .

¿Alguien me pudiera ayudar?

Comment: `T[""]` no es parte de la sintaxis.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Busqueda de comparacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267361/busqueda-de-comparacion)